# How can I swap form values in table rows without swapping the table rows using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dom-traversal

I am trying to swap the form values in row1 with the form values of row2 without swapping the rows. Can someone show me away to achieve this in pure javascript, vanilla JS, or jquery. I made the table rows shorter with just two rows, but the actual table consists of 17 rows. Please look very closely at the ids and form values in the third example.

When the UP or DOWN button is not click, the table looks like this in simple form:

```
   <form id="menuitems">
    <table class="toolbaritems">
       <tbody class="sortable">
       <tr id="row1">
          <td><button class="up_arrow">UP</button></td>
          <td><input value="1></td>
          <td><select><option="1" selected></option></select></td>
          <td><select><option="1a" selected></option></select></td>
       </tr>
       <tr id="row2">
          <td><button class="down_arrow">DOWN</button></td>
          <td><input value="2"></td>
          <td><select><option="2" selected></option></select></td>
          <td><select><option="2a" selected></option></select></td>
       </tr>
      <tr><td><input type="submit" value="SAVE"></td></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>
```

This the code currently - When the UP or DOWN buttons are clicked the table looks like this:

```
   <form id="menuitems">
    <table class="toolbaritems">
       <tbody class="sortable">
       <tr id="row2">
          <td><button class="up_arrow">UP</button></td>
          <td><input value="2"></td>
          <td><select><option="2" selected></option></select></td>
          <td><select><option="2a" selected></option></select></td>
       </tr>
       <tr id="row1">
          <td><button class="down_arrow">DOWN</button></td>
          <td><input value="1"></td>
          <td><select><option="1" selected></option></select></td>
          <td><select><option="1a" selected></option></select></td>
       </tr>
      <tr><td><input type="submit" value="SAVE"></td></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

This is what I am trying to accomplish - The values of the inputs should swap except for the tr. Notices the tr ids remain the same but form values are swapped:

```
<form id="menuitems">
    <table class="toolbaritems">
       <tbody class="sortable">
       <tr id="row1">
          <td><button class="down_arrow">DOWN</button></td>
          <td><input value="2"></td>
          <td><select><option="2" selected></option></select></td>
          <td><select><option="2a" selected></option></select></td>
       </tr>
       <tr id="row2">
          <td><button class="up_arrow">UP</button></td>
          <td><input value="1"></td>
          <td><select><option="1" selected></option></select></td>
          <td><select><option="1a" selected></option></select></td>
       </tr>
      <tr><td><input type="submit" value="SAVE"></td></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Firstly, instead of <option="1"> , the correct syntax is <option value="1">

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to rearrange each individual form element, this just swaps the entire row, which has the same result with a lot less effort:

```js
$('.down_arrow').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').insertAfter($(this).closest('tr').next());
});

$('.up_arrow').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').insertBefore($(this).closest('tr').prev());
});
```

```css
table tr:first-child .up_arrow {
  opacity: 0
}
table tr:last-child .down_arrow {
  opacity: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- I took the liberty of fixing up the broken <option> tags here.  If that was supposed to be two separate <select>s, this code will still work exactly the same -->
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button class="down_arrow">↓</button>
      <button class="up_arrow">↑</button>
    </td>
    <td><input value="1"></td>
    <td><select><option>1</option><option>1a</option></select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button class="down_arrow">↓</button>
      <button class="up_arrow">↑</button>
    </td>
    <td><input value="2"></td>
    <td><select><option>2</option><option>2a</option></select>
    </td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
      <button class="down_arrow">↓</button>
      <button class="up_arrow">↑</button>
    </td>
    <td><input value="3"></td>
    <td><select><option>3</option><option>3a</option></select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button class="down_arrow">↓</button>
      <button class="up_arrow">↑</button>
    </td>
    <td><input value="4"></td>
    <td><select><option>4</option><option>4a</option></select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It may be better to bind the events to the table itself instead of each individual button:

```
$('table').on('click','.down_arrow',function() {...});
```

That way you can add or remove table rows programmatically without having to add new bindings.  (In that vein, in general be wary of using `.html()` to overwrite parts of the the DOM, as it will blow away any event bindings you may have already included.)

Comment: Should've mentioned that, maybe.  Are there specific IDs on these input fields that need to be preserved even if the values change, or are you depending on document order?

Comment: If you're depending on document order to control the submitted form values, this will still work.  If there are different IDs or field names per row, you need to include how exactly you're managing that in the question (especially if the available options in each select might be different for each row, that would complicate this quite a bit.)

Comment: (Also your original code would also have moved any field names or field IDs along with the values, since you were copying the contents of the entire `<td>` -- what gives?)

Comment: If you submit a form with three fields with the same name, they will be sent to the server in document order. Swapping the rows will change that that order, and therefore change how the data is sent to the server.    If you are using some other method to control the order in which the server receives the data, you need to explain what you're doing; just asking the same thing repeatedly in the same words is not going to get you any closer to an answer.

Comment: Well, ask people how to swap rows, that's what they're going to tell you how to do.  No, I'm not willing to handhold you through this on Skype, sorry.

Comment: Swapping individual cels' innerHTML would do exactly the same as swapping the rows, the original form field names and IDs would still correspond with their original values, it'd be as if you didn't swap anything.  Swapping just the field values and not their names or IDs would make somewhat more sense, except that that leaves open the question of what to do with the `<select>`s with different options in each row.  After all of this conversation I still haven't gotten a coherent explanation of what it is you're trying to accomplish, and I'm frankly done trying to extract one. Best of luck.